# How to smooth the change of player's direction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, vector, motion

I want to smooth the change of player's direction. I have a simple motion script, but when I go ahead and start going backwards, I want my character to start "sliding". There's an example on gif file - https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIRA5.jpg. I tried to do it but it's crazy(

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Moving : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    Transform frogTransform;
    Vector3 now = new Vector3();
    Vector3 Now
    {
        get
        {
            if (now == null)
            {
                return Vector3.zero;
            }
            else
            {
                return now;
            }
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            now = Vector3.Lerp(now, Vector3.forward, 0.5f); //this doesn't help me (nothing changes)
            frogTransform.Translate(now * 0.1f);
            now = Vector3.forward;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            now = Vector3.Lerp(now, Vector3.back, 0.5f);
            frogTransform.Translate(now * 0.1f);
            now = Vector3.back;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            now = Vector3.Lerp(now, Vector3.right, 0.5f);
            frogTransform.Translate(now * 0.1f);
            now = Vector3.right;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            now = Vector3.Lerp(now, Vector3.left, 0.5f);
            frogTransform.Translate(now * 0.1f);
            now = Vector3.left;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If dealing with `RigidBody` you do not want to use `transform.Translate` at all. If you want to go this way rather use [`Rigidbody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html). `Lerp` with `0.5` as factor simply means every step you set the vector to the middle between current and target Vector ... but the target Vector is actually never reached!

Comment: I will just assume that the way your brackets are set here is a typo, right? also note that a [`Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) is a `struct` and by default has the same value as `Vector3.zero` .. it will never be `null` so your `if(now == null)` (and thereby the entire property) is totally redundant

Comment: There is a function in `Vector3` called `slerp` which is short for smooth lerp. It's been a while since I worked in Unity but I'm pretty sure that you shouldn't have to rely on rigidbody if you want to move like the linked gif. Transform functions should be enough if you want physic-less movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your answer I see you're using Transform.Translate and that is not the tool to apply Unity Physics (and create effects as sliding).

To apply the slide effect you can add a [Rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) to your gameobject.

Then you can use [Rigidbody.AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) to direct your movement.

As soon as you change the direction/force you will see the sliding effect. Consider that you can tweak the mass and the drag of your rigidbody to have different kind of sliding effects.

Your code would become.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Moving : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Rigidbody rigidbody;

    [SerializeField] float accelerationForce = 5f;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.forward * accelerationForce, ForceMode.Impulse);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.back * accelerationForce, ForceMode.Impulse);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.right * accelerationForce, ForceMode.Impulse);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.left * accelerationForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

You also can check [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBDWTjn05eg) and [this other tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AB0R606bRk).

Comment: I need smooth change of direction when I move my character by WASD. When my character goes forward and I start holding S (back), he should not go back sharply, but slow down and slowly start moving backwards.

Comment: That is exactly what RigidBody AddForce would do.

Comment: But this will not make the object slowly pick up speed after stopping.

Comment: If you show the code related to your implementation and the values you set in the rigidbody I'll check what is happening there. You might add it to the question. IE try adding a very large mass and use the force as Impulse.

Comment: I still confirm the solution. You're using Transform.Translate and not Rigidbody.AddForce. I sent the script using rigidbody.